# How to consume ajax method from differenet class in typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typescript

I am new to typescript and ajax.
I have written a method in typescript to be used across classes for ajax call:

```
myFunc(value: string): JQueryPromise<any>
{
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:GOOGL",
        data: "",
        success: function(value?: string) {
            console.log("success");
            dfd.resolve(value);
        },

        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        dataType: "jsonp"
    });

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

But I am facing problem while consuming it using `when` and `then` of jquery

```
var promiseOne = this.myFunc("value1");
    $.when(promiseOne).then((valFromPromiseOne: any) =>
    {
         alert(valFromPromiseOne);
    });
```

I am getting typescript error saying :
`Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target`

If someone can tell me the best way to get the result from my ajax method .. I have tried with jquery deffered but was facing the same issue

Comment: Did you try  `this.myFunc("value1").done((valFromPromiseOne: any) =>
    {
         alert(valFromPromiseOne);
    });`

Comment: Hi Nico, with your approach only success part is handled .. can you suggest a way to handle both success and error

Answer (score 0):

According to the jquery documentation on the [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object something like this should work.

```
this.myFunc("value1")
.done((valFromPromiseOne: any) => { alert(valFromPromiseOne); })
.fail(() => { alert("fail")});
```